# Basic Calculator using "Clojure’s"

Tags: clojure

We have to a write code in "Clojure’s" using case extension -

```
(defn calculator [x a b]
  (case x "+" (println (+ a b))
          "-" (println (- a b))
          "*" (println (* a b))
          "/" (println (/ a b)))
  
  )
)  
(def x (read-line))
(def a (Integer/parseInt (clojure.string/trim (read-line))))
(def b (Integer/parseInt (clojure.string/trim (read-line))))
(calculator x a b)
```

Please help us in above code i.e. where we went wrong.

Comment: Is that your entire program? What do you see that indicates a problem?

Comment: When we running it it throwing an error .. saying code is incorrect...

Comment: thanks found issue extra ) was there thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have one extra paren on calculator function.

```clj
(defn calculator [x a b]
  (case x "+" (println (+ a b))
          "-" (println (- a b))
          "*" (println (* a b))
          "/" (println (/ a b))))

(def x (read-line))
(def a (Integer/parseInt (clojure.string/trim (read-line))))
(def b (Integer/parseInt (clojure.string/trim (read-line))))

(calculator x a b)
```